# arithmetic and cast pointers and structures

Tags: c, casting, structure, pointer-arithmetic

I've got an array of structures define as follows.

```
typedef struct
{
    _id customer_id;          // unsigned int (4 bytes)
    char customer_name [40];
    char customer_surname [40];
    char customer_vat [40];
    char customer_add [60];
    char customer_email [60];
    char customer_land_phone [22];
    char customer_mob_phone [22];
    time_t customer_creation_date;    // long int (8 bytes)
} _Customer_Struct;
```

and an array of structures...

```
_Customer_Struct customers [x];   // x is irrelevant
```

and an array of offsets to the members of my array of structures...

```
const size_t offset [9] =
{
    (&customers[0].customer_id - (_id *) customers) / sizeof (_id), // stores 0
    (&customers[0].customer_name[0] - (char *) customers) / sizeof (char), // stores 4
    (&customers[0].customer_surname[0] - (char *) customers) / sizeof (char), // 44
    (&customers[0].customer_vat[0] - (char *) customers) / sizeof (char), // 84
    (&customers[0].customer_add[0] - (char *) customers) / sizeof (char), // 124
    (&customers[0].customer_email[0] - (char *) customers) / sizeof (char), // 184
    (&customers[0].customer_land_phone[0] - (char *) customers) / sizeof (char), // 244
    (&customers[0].customer_mob_phone[0] - (char *) customers) / sizeof (char), // 266
    (&customers[0].customer_creation_date - (time_t *) customers) / sizeof (time_t) // 4 what...?
};
```

Next to each line there is a comment with the value stored for each expression. Now, take a look on the last line
`(&customers[0].customer_creation_date - (time_t *) customers) / sizeof (time_t)`. If I understand, this is supposed to cast the base address of `customers` (the array) to ***time_t***, which equals ***long int***,  subtract the value of its address from `&customers[0].customer_creation_date`, yield a partial result of the form n*`(time_t)`, and finally divide it by the size in bytes of `(time_t)` producing the corresponding offset in bytes. Basically **the same as in the former eight lines**.

**Question1: Why is this expression yielding 4 instead of 288?**

**Question2: Why does it work if I cast it to char instead?**

`(char *)&customers[0].customer_creation_date - (char *) customers) / sizeof (char)` actually produces 288.

Comment: Instead of calculating the offsets yourself, use [`offsetof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/offsetof)

Comment: @Pablo - I didn't even know the function. I'm going to read about it. Gracias!

Comment: `288/8/8 = 4`. That's all there is to it. Pointer arithmetic does the division, and then you divide again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing pointer math to figure the offsets, which is valid, but remember that pointer math is meant to produce an integer that can be used as an index into an array of the type the pointer is pointing to.

so:

```
(&customers[0].customer_creation_date - (time_t *) customers)
```

is figuring out what a hypothetical 'j' would be such that:

```
((time_t *)&customers)[j] == &customers.customer_creation_date
```

And when you cast the pointers to (char *) the pointer math is done in characters, which is what you mean.  The same applies to the customer_id, except that since it's first, it's offset is zero anyway.

Comment: That's my point. Maths are done in whatever you cast it to. If you want the results in chars, just divide by `sizeof (chosen-type)`. It's exactly what I did in the former 8 lines. Even more, if I did cast the other 8 lines to something else, they would still yield the right value. But doing it to the correct type here doesn't seem to work and I don't understand why. Thanks!

Comment: I'm curious how you intend to be using these offsets, as indexes from a `(char *)` address, or as indexes from a `(member-type *)` address, i.e.  for customer_creation_date you'd do something like `((time_t *)&customer)[offset[8]]` as opposed to `((char *)&customer)[offset[8]]`  In either case you don't need the `/ sizeof((type))`s  in the first case  `((char *)&customers[0].<field> - (char *)customers`  (which is what `offset` will do) will work, and if you intend the second case then  `&customers[0].<field> - (<field-type> *)customers`  will work.

Comment: Yes, it'd be easier to just use pointers or deference each entry individually. What I didn't mention is that once I find a match in any of the fields, when doing a look up, I'm planing to copy the whole entry to dynamically allocated position in memory. After using `memcpy` to copy this whole entry of my table to memory, the structure would no longer exists (in the new memory chunk), hence there is no way to read a particular field in the recently copied `customers`. Not with pointers or through member naming. Only by offsets. I'm opened to suggestions btw. Thanks!

Comment: I'm curious why after the `memcpy()` only offsets will work to access the elements; I just want to clarify that you understand that you can `memcpy(buf, &customers[j], sizeof(_Customer_struct))` and still access it with the structure definition, either via `((_Cust_struct *)buf)->customer_creation_date` or by having set `buf` up as a ptr to `_Customer_struct` in the first place, as in `buf = &new_customer`.  Unions can also often be useful in situations like this.  Perhaps if you tell us a bit more about what the destination of the copy looks like I can suggest something more useful :)

Comment: I'm glad you clarified that! I thought `memcpy`ing from a structure to a new location in memory wouldn't keep the structure's shape in the new location. That's why I needed offsets and not pointers. I'm trying to iterate through an array of structures, each of them containing 9 elements (id, name, ...), look for a match in any of the fields, say `customers[x].customer_id == 7`, and `memcpy` the whole matching structure/S (array element), to a one expandable position in memory. All this hassle is to be able to get the members of the structure in the dynamically allocated memory

Comment: I'm going to try what you said. If it works I'm going to have to eat my posts :)  Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're welcome.  Structure layout is guaranteed to be consistent __provided that__ the same compiler and the exact same structure definitions are used (as in the same header file was included.)  One thing to keep in mind is that structure layout sometimes includes small holes for alignment of the members, and no guarantees are made that the bytes in those holes will stay the same, or be the same for two structures initialised member by member with the same data.  Sometimes people think that if `memcpy()` can copy structures then `memcmp()` can compare them, but that is not correct!

Comment: I read something about alignment involving the `#pragma pack(push,1)` directive. Besides, I trying what you said and seems to work. However, I keep getting a nasty error when trying to `printf` from a `long` structure element (coincidence?) `warning: unknown conversion type character 0xa in format [-Wformat=]`. Weird! It seems to work fine if I don't try to print a `long` value, `int`s and `char *`s have no problem.

Comment: I'd have to see the format string, likely it needs a `"%ld"` rather than a `"%d"`. I'm glad things are working!  `#pragma`s can affect how the compiler packs structures, but so long as the same `#pragma`s are in place for all modules compiled with references to a given structure, every instance of it will have exactly the same layout. Sometimes we think a structure definition implies some layout information resides with the structure itself, but really `struct` statements just define an "access policy" for the compiler to use when acting on that structure's members.

Comment: Sorry, I've been away for some time. It's working fine. My mistake, I was using `%l` instead of `%ld`. Regarding the former, I'm seriously thinking of start reading about GCC.